# Long Equations vs. Overwriting variables

Tags: javascript

So i have a relatively long (in a text editor) equation and was wondering wether it is best to keep it like this or re write it as over writing variables? Is there a performance difference?

```
((((hoursPerWeek * (100 - percentageLoaded)) * (motorKw * 1.25) * 0.35) * 50) * (pencePerKwh / 100)) / 100
```

Comment: Why overwrite them? You can make new (meaningful) ones instead. Grouping calculations helps as well (such as placing `100 - percentageLoaded` and `/100` together (and express them as a ratio).

Comment: Well, you could get rid of most of the parens...

Comment: Even if there is a performance difference, there's no way it'll be significant enough to make it worth making your code less legible. Don't fall into the trap of prematurely optimizing!

Comment: In JS, it's hardly ever worth worrying about performance to start with - instead focus on readability and correctness.  When you have a measurable performance problem, then worry about performance.

Comment: I tend do make separate functions for more complicated (in terms of readability and/or complexity) computations (especially, when you need them alot) even if it's just to improve the readability. `function weeklyCosts(params...){return <computation>}` and then you just do `if (weeklyCosts() > x)`. Modern minifiers most likely inline such stuff anyway, but at least your code got readable (and testable).

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've now re written the function to use variables instead, thanks for your answer. I can't help but think that "When you have a measurable performance problem, then worry about performance" isn't best practice though...

Comment: @Jamie Note I said _"hardly ever"_ - if you're writing something where performance is needed (like graphics rendering code), then yes you should think about performance when writing your code, but even still I'd think more about readability first.  In most general cases in JS, things will be fast enough - the latest engines have got _very_ good at optimising your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't "overwrite" variables (as in reusing the same named variables to represent different values at different points in code), but I would certainly recommend breaking out the calculations into variables named appropriately for their purpose.

```
var percentageNotLoaded = 100 - percentageLoaded;
var unusedPerWeek = hoursPerWeek * percentageNotLoaded;
// etc...
```

There will not be a measurable difference in performance. The JIT compiler will most likely optimize away the variables themselves to use CPU registers and memory loads just as it would have in your original code. Even if it didn't, I highly doubt that this calculation is being done so often in your JavaScript code that it would represent a performance bottleneck. As the other commenters have noted, it's best to focus on readability first, and only worry about performance when it becomes a measurable problem.